# Multiple home screen shortcuts created on Nexus 7 Tab

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have created my App's shortcut on Home Screen when app launched and it is working fine across all Devices

But, on Nexus tab it creates multiple shortcuts on every app launch ?

How can I create Shortcut only once when App installed and remove it on App uninstalled ?

```
private void AddShortcutIconToHomeScreen() {
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, EmployeeListActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Device Tracker");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
        Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may remove shortcut if exists by using method `removeShortcut()` before calling your method `AddShortcutIconToHomeScreen()`:

**method:**

```
        private void removeShortcut() {

        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, EmployeeListActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Device Tracker");

        addIntent
                .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    }
```

and inside manifest file, add the permission,

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Comment: Thanks Mehul. basically it will create or remove shortcut when app luanched for first time. How can I call this methods when App installed or removed ?

Comment: using  removeShortcut() method also I could see multiple icons only on Nexus 7 tab, It works perfect without removeShortcut() method on all othe devices

Comment: if you want to do some actions only for first ever launch of your app, then you need to maintain the track in `SharedPreference` about it.so it won't perform same action in next launch.And about acknowledgement of uninstalling, android doesn't have such feature.

Answer (score 0):

Solved My problem using `SharedPreference`

```
  private void AddShortcutIconToHomeScreen() {
    boolean mboolean = false;

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0);
    mboolean = settings.getBoolean("FIRST_RUN", false);
    if (!mboolean) {
      // do the thing for the first time
      settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("FIRST_RUN", true);
      editor.commit();
      Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, EmployeeListActivity.class);
      shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

      Intent addIntent = new Intent();
      addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
      addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Device Tracker");
      addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
          Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
              R.drawable.ic_launcher));
      addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
      addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
      getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    } else {
      // other time your app loads
    }
  }
```

Added AndroidManifest.xml Permissions.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```